# Suzuki Intruder VL1500 Ignition Coil Difference in Front and Rear

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, ignition, power

My Suzuki Intruder VL 1500 (1998) has a front and rear ignition coil according to the OEM specifications... I'm curious if these are essentially the same even though the have different part numbers.

**What is difference in a front and rear ignition coil? Can either be replaced with a generic ignition coil?**

*From the service manual:*

> On carbureted models, the ignition system consists of a signal generator, igniter with an 8-bit microprocessor (IC), two ignition
>   coils and two park plugs. During operation, the IC in the igniter
>   receives input from the signal generator, throttle position sensor,
>   and MAP sensor to determine the ignition timing for the operating
>   conditions.
>
> The IC sends a signal to the ignition coil, the primary winding turns
>   off and on, and a high voltage is induced in the secondary winding,
>   which fires the spark plug.

*Are here are the part numbers for the coils in question:*

- 33420-10F10 (replaces part #33420-10F00) COIL ASSY, IGNITION FRONT
- 33420-38B00  COIL ASSY, IGNITION REAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The front and rear coils may simply have different shapes due to their locations, otherwise their function is the same ie to generate a spark based on a given signal.

As for can they be replaced by a generic ignition coil, that depends what you mean by a "generic ignition coil".

If the replacement is made by a third party and says it will fit and work then yes. But if you are picking a generic item at random just because it says "coil" on it then probably no....

Comment: This is exactly right. Closer investigation has revealed the shape is the only difference and mechanically (electronically) they're the same part.